# Why does the "where" command not work as expected for full paths?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

Peruse these commands and the output:

```
where pg_ctl
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_ctl.exe

where pg_ctl.exe
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_ctl.exe

where "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_ctl.exe"
ERROR: Invalid pattern is specified in "path:pattern".
```

Why does the last one return an error instead of outputting itself/succeeding?

I have to be able to reliably enter *either* a "command" or a full path to an executable to this command to determine if it's an executable command or not.

Checking the error codes, I get this:

```
0
0
2
```

From `where /?`:

```
NOTE: The tool returns an error level of 0 if the search is
    successful, of 1 if the search is unsuccessful and
    of 2 for failures or errors.
```

In other words, it doesn't return a proper 1 (search is unsuccessful) for the last command (the full path), but a 2 (failure or error). But even if it did return 1 as the exit code, that would still be wrong. It's supposed to return 0, because the path exists, so it is an executable command.

Comment: The return code of 2 is actually  the proper response in the example you provided.

Answer (score 5):

Where is a command for finding files. If you specify its full path, then what is the point of using where?

You can always use

```
if exist c:\path\filename.ext echo File does exist.
```

But if you really want to use the where command, then use it the way it was meant to be used. Use the /r parameter to specify the path, and put the command you are searching for as separate parameter.

Like so:

```
C:\>where /r "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin" pg_ctl.exe
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_ctl.exe

C:\>_
```

Comment: I second  ***then what is the point of using where?*** ???

Answer (score 0):

The clue lies in the message `ERROR: Invalid pattern is specified in "path:pattern".`

```
C:\Users>where /?

WHERE [/R dir] [/Q] [/F] [/T] pattern...
[...]
    pattern  Specifies the search pattern for the files to match.
             Wildcards * and ? can be used in the pattern. The
             "$env:pattern" and "path:pattern" formats can also be
             specified, where "env" is an environment variable and
             the search is done in the specified paths of the "env"
             environment variable. These formats should not be used
             with /R. The search is also done by appending the
             extensions of the PATHEXT variable to the pattern.
[...]

Examples:
[...]
    WHERE "c:\windows;c:\windows\system32:*.dll"
```

As you can see, the *search pattern* is a **single wildcard** to match, with an optional environment variable or path to search from. Since you're passing a path, it'll expect another `:` followed by the pattern. The pattern is nowhere to be found so the error is expected

Although as said, if you already have the full path then there's no point in using `where`